# Links inside org-mode tables are not typeset in monospaced font

Tags: org-mode, fonts, org-table, org-link

While the default is a proportional font, I told `org-mode` to use a monospaced font in tables:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (variable-pitch-mode t)))
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (set-face-attribute 'org-table nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch))
```

Yet for some reason this does not affect links inside tables, which then screw up the alignment (Emacs 24.5, Org-mode  8.2.10):

[image]

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: With `C-u C-x =` (what-cursor-position) it shows that the link inside a table has face `org-link`, not `org-table`. I don't know if there's an easy way to do what you want (merge the faces somehow), but if you don't find anything else, a cheesy workaround would be to make all links fixed-pitch.